# MySQL IN clause query

Tags: mysql, inner-join, in-clause

Simply, I want to find a solution for testing if one column value exits within another, or not, across tables. I've naturally jumped to 'NOT IN clause' but I've also discovered I can't use a colum name within the bracket (b.full_name)

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tbl1_name a 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl2_name 
    ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE 
    a.name NOT IN (b.full_name);
```

What clause can I use to achieve what I'm looking for etc.

Comment: IN checks if a value exists in a list of other values or fields. This solution would just be checking if a.name does not equal b.full_name.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply do

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1_name a
INNER JOIN tbl2_name ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.name <> b.full_name;
```

The `IN` keyword is normally used to check for multiple values example

```
NOT IN ('A', 'B');
```

Or

```
NOT IN (subquery);
```

Comment: @user2505513 Got no feedback from this, did this answer worked for you ? Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery after not in clause and select all the names from the table b. Hope it will resolve your problem.

```
Select * from table1 a inner join table2 b 
on a.id=b.id 
where a.name not in
(Select names from table2)
```

Comment: sub queries have to be avoided when possible! why suggest to use them when there are much simpler solutions

Answer (score 0):

you can perform that using subqueries, this way :

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1_name a
WHERE a.name IN (SELECT b.full_name FROM tbl2_name b WHERE a.id = b.id);
```